# What is $x$ satisfying the condition?

Tags: problem-solving, transcendental-equations

What is $x$ such that $3^{\log (x)}-2^{\log(x)}=2^{\log (x+1)}-3^{\log (x-1)}$?

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5Elog%20(x)-2%5Elog(x)%3D2%5Elog%20(x%2B1)-3%5Elog%20(x-1)) says $x=2.47\ldots$ but I couldn't get it manually.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: why would this have a closed form???

Comment: @WillJagy No idea! It looks like the LHS is increasing after some point and the RHS is decreasing. Both cross at only $x=2.47\ldots$!

Comment: Sigh. Where did you get the problem??

Comment: @WillJagy Was playing with logarithms a bit. Maybe it already exists somewhere. No idea again! Did you try?

Answer (score 1):

We can obtain decent approximation of the solution.

Let $x=y+1$ and consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(y)=\Big[3^{\log (y+1)}-2^{\log(y+1)}\Big]-\Big[2^{\log (y+2)}-3^{\log (y)}\Big]$$ Using $y_0=1$, perform **one** single iteration of Newton-like methods of order $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & y_n & \text{method} \\
 2 & 1.505656785 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 & 1.475784581 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 & 1.480463468 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 & 1.479522210 & \text{no name} \\
 6 & 1.479745762 & \text{no name} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \\
\infty & 1.479698894 & \text{no name}
\end{array}
\right)$$